# Making a list of User Defined Objects available throughout the application

Tags: android

I have created some business objects which are created with the data from the database. I am doing this so that I don't want to hit the DB again and again. The business objects implements parcelable interface. So I can put the arraylist of business objects to the next activity. I am using APILevel 8 so there is no point of using SharedPreferences.editor putExtraSet. Even if I am using API level 11 or above. PutExtraSet can have only set of Strings.

How can I make the arrayList or some collection of business objects available for the entire application rather than forwarding from one activity to another?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the Application class.

```
class SomeName extends Application{

    private Object obj;
    public Object getObj(){
        return obj;
    }
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

The application class is global to your application and can be accessed by any activity by calling

```
((SomeName)getApplication).getObj();
```

or just keep a reference in you Activity if you use it a lot

```
SomeName someName = (SomeName)getApplication();
someName.getObj();
```

In the androidManifest.xml the following has to be done.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="SomeName">
```

Comment: Got it working thanks. But it should be getApplication() rather than getApplicationContext(). And in the androidmanifest.xml in the application tag android:name="SomeName" should be added

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class and make these objects **`private static`** .And you can reference these as Classname.objectname.

```
class Global{
      private static Object obj;
      public Object getObject(){
                 return this.obj;
}
 public Object setObject(Object obj){
                this.obj=obj;
}

}
```

In your activity,you can access as Global.getObject() and modify Global.setObject(obj);

Comment: I didn't get it. Can u pls elaborate?

Comment: got it working with triggs answer. Anyways thanks for ur response